# Unable to share image and title with url on facebook through my web page?

Tags: php, html, facebook, share

Unable share image and title with url, also added meta tag for image and title into page but working.
Share working correctly but site other image is showing, not showing the image which I provided. Also not showing my title.
My code:

I used meta tag into header below

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />



<a class="facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.example.com?id=123" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><span class="soc-font-icon"></span><span class="social-text">Share on Facebook</span><span class="screen-reader-text">Share on Facebook</span></a>
```

Comment: on this url http://www.example.com?id=123 you have to put meta data and place image on metadata then it will show image [this will explain](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/images/)

Comment: it should be on any website not in localhost

Comment: Also placed image on meta tag and testing on server not localhost but still not working. Can you share a link of code example, then it will be very helpfull.

Comment: Also edit my question with added meta tag.

Comment: I highly doubt that the real domain of your website is nytimes.com. You should put in the real data in these meta tags, not fake ones (especially the URL, which - most probably - it is used to uniquely identify resources on FB).

Comment: From the website , where I want to share, image url should be the same website image url? Can I use different site image url?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's sharing debugger can help you figure out what's wrong: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Also tested.Into facebook debugger we can test with only url not with other data.

Comment: @ajoy FB's share debugger is exactly for previewing/debugging the embedded meta values on any give page:
"You can use the Sharing Debugger to see the information that is used when your website content is shared on Facebook, Messenger and other places."